# About touch coordinate between iPhone 4s, 5, 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Fyi, I am new to Xcode programming for iOS. 
I've written a simple game and tested on actual iPhone 4s and is working. 
As I only own iPhone 4s, I can only simulate my game with iOS simulator for higher iPhone version.
The problem I observed for higher iPhone version is that the image is scaled, therefore the touch location is no longer valid.

PS: I do not use any `UIButton`. I am using `CGRectMake` to create the button and later declare the touch position as shown below.

```
-(void) touchBegan: (CGPoint) p 
{
    if (p.x > 0 && p.x < 100 && p.y > 0 && p.y < 30) myscore = 1;
}
```

So my question is, will the touch displacement seen in the simulator appear the same in the actual device? If yes, does it mean that I need to declare the touch boundary for each iPhone version?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix the touch location regardless of the device you're using, the easier way is to, as said before, click and drag a Button on the storyboard and use Auto-Layout to fix the location of the button For instance,  you can set the button to appear 10px down and 10px right from the top-left corner from the containing view and it will appear at the same location regardless of the device used. But I'm sure there's a way to programmatically do the exact same thing

PS: wanted to post a comment and not an answer, but I don't have enough rep...

Comment: This seems more like an answer as it is and not a comment. Will admit would probably be better with some code example but it's still an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will happens in device to. As you comment you can set the bounds for each different device or (i think easier) use a UIButton. Why don't you use it ? Any special reason?

Comment: Hi Christian, Thanks for your reply. I have seen some example of UIButton in other stack overflow forum, and they are using CGRectMake as well to identify the bound. Doesn't this will have the same problem as above? Sample code: button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

Comment: After going through a few more forums, I believe I need to redefine the touch position for each screen size. I was looking for an easier way out but seems like this is the only way.